# How to fix a grepl function with multiple conditions and a if-statement?

Tags: r, if-statement, grepl

I'm trying to pattern match using the grepl function with an ifelse statement but the output is all 0.

I am trying to use pattern match where if a Logo is equal to a "Taco Bell", then it matches these sets of words but not these sets of words. I have tried to use the grepl function with an ifelse statement, but it matches all mentions of the word "Taco".

```
query <- data.frame("id" = 1:5, "Logo" = c('Del Taco','Taco Bell','Del Taco','Taco Bell', 'Del Taco'), "text" = c("Taco Bell","Del Taaco","Tac Bell","Taco Bel","De Taco"))

ifelse(query$Logo=="Taco Bell", 
   ifelse(!grepl("d.el|'Del Taco'", query$text, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE), "0", 
     ifelse(grepl("Taco Bell", query$text, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE),"1","0")),
   NA)
```

The expected output is supposed to be if the Logo column is "Taco Bell" and the text column is "Taco Bell" it is pattern matched/"TRUE". If the Logo column is "Taco Bell" and text column is "Del Taco" it is not matched/"FALSE".

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set?

Comment: I'd recommend you pick a single row of your data where this should return 1, but returns 0, and add that to your post.

Comment: Although, you may just need to get rid of the `!` in the second line

Comment: Because I think "if NOT Del Taco" returns `TRUE` when "if IS Taco Bell" returns `TRUE`, meaning that you'll never get to the "Taco Bell" condition.

Comment: @divibisan thanks I just added an example dataset

Comment: @Mako212 thanks I edited the post with an example dataset

Comment: I assume `x` should be `query`?

Comment: Also check your capitalization of `text`. Is that the problem or a typo?

Comment: Yeah, when I change `x$text` to `x$Text` the above code works for me

Comment: Isn't this just `query$Logo == "Taco Bell" & query$text == "Taco Bell"`?